# Bigquery: compress row having null struct record into a single record

Tags: sql, arrays, google-cloud-platform, struct, google-bigquery

Using Bigquery.
I am trying to combine two columns in `Array<STRUCT<key string, value string>>`.

The below is the query I came up with.
If the value in the either of two columns is `empty` or `null`, instead of creating two `null` struct records, I would like to compress it into a single `null` record.
The records in the green / blue boxes should be only one record rather two empty records.

```sql
SELECT  [
    case when (colA is not NULL and trim(colA) != "") 
        then struct("center" as key, colA as value) 
        else struct(NULL as key, NULL as value) 
    end, 
       
    case when (colB is not NULL and trim(colB) != "") 
        then struct("owner" as key, colB as value) 
        else struct(NULL as key, NULL as value) 
    end
] as labels
FROM `project.dataset.bill`;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the revised version of your query. Try with this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN TRIM(IFNULL(colA, '')) = '' AND TRIM(IFNULL(colB, '')) = '' THEN [STRUCT(NULL AS key, NULL AS value)]
    ELSE ARRAY_CONCAT(
      IF(TRIM(IFNULL(colA, '')) != '', [STRUCT("center" AS key, colA AS value)], []),
      IF(TRIM(IFNULL(colB, '')) != '', [STRUCT("owner" AS key, colB AS value)], [])
    )
  END AS labels
FROM `project.dataset.bill`;
```